# xslt items count in every page

Tags: xml, apache, xslt, apache-fop

I have XML data and I need to display the data using a dynamic table in XSLT and generate a PDF file using Apache FOP:

- this table can span multiple pages based on number of items in the XML
- in each and every page in the footer I need to display the items count on that page. For example a page can accommodate 10 items and if the xml has 15 nodes, I need to display item count as 10 in the first page and 5 in the second page footer.

**How can I achieve this result?**

**XML input:**

```
<items>
    <itemPin>123..</itemPin>
    <amount></amount>
</items>
<items>
    <itemPin>123..</itemPin>
    <amount></amount>
</items>
<items>
    <itemPin>123..</itemPin>
    <amount></amount>
</items>
<items>
    <itemPin>123..</itemPin>
    <amount></amount>
</items>
<items>
    <itemPin>123..</itemPin>
    <amount></amount>
</items>
<items>
    <itemPin>123..</itemPin>
    <amount></amount>
</items>
```

**Sample XSLT used for dynamic table**

```
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">
            <fo:table-row height="0.2in">
                <fo:table-cell padding="0pt" display-align="center">
                    display item pin here
                </fo:table-cell >
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body >
    </fo:block>
</fo:flow>

<fo:static-content flow-name="page-footer">
    <fo:block-container height="1.60in" width="10.54in" >
        <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" height="0.43in" left="0in" top="0in" width="3.32in" >
            <fo:block>
                <fo:inline font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold">
                    <xsl:text>Total Items This Page: </xsl:text>
                </fo:inline>
    </fo:block-container>
</fo:static-content>
```

Comment: Post u r XML, Required output, and tried XSLT code.

Comment: <items>
<itemPin>123..</itemPin>
<amount></amount>
</items>
<items>
<itemPin>123..</itemPin>
<amount></amount>
</items>
<items>
<itemPin>123..</itemPin>
<amount></amount>
</items>
<items>
<itemPin>123..</itemPin>
<amount></amount>
</items>
<items>
<itemPin>123..</itemPin>
<amount></amount>
</items>
<items>
<itemPin>123..</itemPin>
<amount></amount>
</items>

Comment: Xslt of the dynamic table is <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
<fo:block>
<fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">

 <fo:table-row height="0.2in">
  <fo:table-cell padding="0pt" display-align="center">
  display item pin here
  </fo:table-cell >
 
 </fo:table-row>

</fo:table-body >
</fo:block>
</fo:flow>

Comment: footer content is <fo:static-content flow-name="page-footer">
 <fo:block-container height="1.60in" width="10.54in" >
    <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" height="0.43in" left="0in" top="0in" width="3.32in" >
     <fo:block>
      <fo:inline font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold">
       <xsl:text>Total Items This Page: </xsl:text>
      </fo:inline>
 </fo:block-container>
</fo:static-content>